# laravel Api Resource. Delete Request Session expired. Only Get method Working

Tags: laravel, api, resources

Eloquent: API Resources
I am Trying to Crud a table using POSTMAN and laravel Api Resources. ]
Although using get method i can get all the data. When i use delete or post method, it returns an error of session expired.
Thanks in advance.[Image Of POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7dby.png)

[Image of routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1c2Q.png)

Comment: Do you set auth middleware on your store method? Do you set route on web.php or in api.php?

Comment: Sorry,i am new in coding. i was following a tutorial.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pc6cgisbKE&t=1352s . and i have edited the question for image of route. Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're missing the CRSF token, which would explain why `HTTP GET`'s are working. One option to work around this is to disable the CSRF middleware when working in your development environment. Simplest solution is to open up `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` and set:

```
protected $except = [
    '*',
];
```

The * is a wildcard-like option that will disable CSRF verification for all routes. Obviously ideal solution would to be to disable it on a higher level only when working on local development, but the provided answer is a quick solution.

See the Laravel documentation on [CSRF Excluding URI's](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble. I found the problem,actually i was posting the routes in web.php instead of api.php . That was why i was getting the errors. Thankyou for the concern.

Comment: That makes no sense, the `api.php` routes file is identical to that of the `web.php` routes file only the api middleware grouping contains additional middleware. I find it very odd that this was your issue. **Edit:** Additionally, I can't reproduce the error on my side by moving all my routes to the `api.php` file with a fresh install so I'm not sure how you came to this conclusion?